# What are the pros and cons of these different function definitions?

Tags: elixir

I currently learning elixir and I was wondering if this three implementation are really a matter of choice or there are some best practice related to performance or other things, in other words is there a best one ?

My first implementation is the third one(... I know), but if I had to choose, I will definitly choose the second one. The first one seems weird to me because I define the function 3 times

Thx !

```
  @spec count(list) :: non_neg_integer
  def count(l), do: count(l, 0)
  defp count([], acc), do: acc
  defp count([_ | tail], acc), do: count(tail, acc + 1)


  @spec count(list) :: non_neg_integer
  def count(l) do
      case l do
          [] -> 0
          [_|tail] -> 1 + count(tail)
      end
  end


@spec count(list) :: non_neg_integer
  def count(l) do
      do_count(l, counter)
  end

  defp do_count(list, counter \\ 0) do
      cond do
          list == [] -> counter
          true ->
              counter = counter + 1
              do_count(tl(list), counter)
      end
  end
```

Comment: I am sorely tempted to change the title of your question but that seems like it might be editorial overreach. Please make the title of your question something more descriptive.

Comment: fair enough ... could you give me the title you would use please ?

Comment: One that comes to mind is "Are Multiple Function Heads A Better Approach To This Problem?"  Your existing title is just pretty generic.

Comment: well that's not exactly what I wanted to said... What do you think about: "what are the pros and cons of these differents function definition"

Comment: "What are the pros and cons of these different function definitions?" sounds good to me.

Answer (score 8):

> I was wondering if this three implementation are really a matter of choice or there are some best practice related to performance or other things, in other words is there a best one?

One important difference between them is that the first and the third implementations are [tail recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call), while the second one isn't. This means that the second implementation will use `O(n)` memory to execute on a list of `n` of elements, while the first and the third will use `O(1)`.

The third solution uses `cond` where a pattern matching solution would have been shorter and most likely faster.

You can rewrite

```
cond do
  list == [] -> counter
  true ->
    counter = counter + 1
    do_count(tl(list), counter)
end
```

to

```
case list do
  [] -> counter
  [_|tail] ->
    counter = counter + 1
    do_count(tail, counter)
end
```

which is almost the same as the first implementation.

The first one is definitely the most idiomatic and most likely the fastest of the three.

Answer (score 0):

You can always translate a multi-clause function to a `case` statement and vice versa. Note that Elixir is a functional programming language, so it's very idiomatic to write multi-clause function.

As for `cond`, will be the last resort if it would take too much work to write multi-clause function.

Back to your question, the first one is the best among three.